# How can I determine which arguments a Python function takes?

Tags: python, function, arguments, pdftotext

Running the following code:

```
pdf = pdftotext.PDF(f,layout='raw')
```

produced this error:

> 'layout' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Is there a way to list which arguments this, and any, function would take?

Comment: `print(help(pdftotext.PDF))`.

Comment: Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [help](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) built-in function of python.

> ## help([object])
>
> Invoke the built-in help system. (**This function is intended for interactive use**.) If no argument is given, the
> interactive help system starts on the interpreter console. If the
> argument is a string, then the string is looked up as the name of a
> module, function, class, method, keyword, or documentation topic, and
> a help page is printed on the console. If the argument is any other
> kind of object, a help page on the object is generated.

Let's say you are coming from Python 2.7 and need help with the `print` function of Python 3. Go to the interactive prompt and type `help(print)`:

```
>>> help(print)
```

> ```
>    Help on built-in function print in module builtins:
>
>    print(...)
>        print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>    
>        Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
>        Optional keyword arguments:
>        file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
>        sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
>        end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>        flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
>    (END)
> ```

As you can see `print` takes 4 keyword arguments (`sep`, `end`, `file`, `flush`). Press `q` when you are done to exit.

Answer (score 1):

help(f) shows documentation and parameters for a python construct f, like a class or function.

Eg on the console

`help(print)`

shows

> ```
> Help on built-in function print in module builtins:
>
> print(...)
>     print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
>     Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
>     Optional keyword arguments:
>     file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
>     sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
>     end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
>     flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
> ```

Help on my new function f ...

`def f():
    None`

shows

> Help on function f in module **main**:
>
> f()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help

Comment: This works scripted but the command line gives me this error: 'NameError: name 'pdftotext' is not defined.' UPDATE: Apologies, it wasn't imported...

Answer (score -1):

`help` function in python can be used to view the documentation for a class or a function. I like to keep an `IPython` interpreter running when coding in python. `IPython` provides operators like `?` and `??` specifically for this purpose.